# LCD Numbers - get my lost 190 bytes back

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, number

Years ago I read the ["Best of Ruby Quiz"](https://pragprog.com/book/fr_quiz/best-of-ruby-quiz) book by James Edward Gray II (also available [online](http://it-ebooks.info/book/8) by now). For problem 2 in the book (which is [problem 14](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz14.html) on his original RubyQuiz site), he mentions a golfed solution in under 300 bytes, even though he is not a big fan of golfing.

So I did wonder if I could beat that and maybe even find a solution of under 200 bytes. So once I beat the current best solution of [256 bytes](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/vframe.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/125898?125671-126412) I sent him a [210 bytes solution](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/246817). Shortly thereafter I found a solution around 190 bytes, but didn't bother to send him that. But over the years I lost these 190 bytes somehow and couldn't find a backup anymore. In any case I know that a under 200 byte solution is possible in ruby (at least with ruby 1.8.7) so I hope some of you will be able to recreate it or maybe even find something better.

Even though I'm mostly interested in ruby solution other language solutions are of course also welcome!

### The Challenge

Create a program which is called on the commandline and takes a non-negative integer as an argument and an optional `-s` argument followed by a positive integer. The default value for `-s` is `2`.

The output should be the input argument in LCD-style adjusted by size by the `-s` parameter.

For example if the program is called like this

```
$ lcd.rb 012345
```

the correct display is this:

```
 --        --   --        --
|  |    |    |    | |  | |
|  |    |    |    | |  | |
           --   --   --   --
|  |    | |       |    |    |
|  |    | |       |    |    |
 --        --   --        --
```

And for this:

```
$ lcd.rb -s 1 6789
```

your program should print this:

```
 -   -   -   -
|     | | | | |
 -       -   -
| |   | | |   |
 -       -   -
```

Note the single column of space between digits in both examples. For other values of `-s`, simply lengthen the `-` and `|` bars.

Of course because this is code golf I have to be more specific than the original quiz about some rules:

- It's ok if your program requires to be explicitly called by an interpreter (e.g. `ruby lcd.rb 1234`), so a shebang line is not required
- It's not required to handle other than the above specified arguments in a sane way (e.g. negative numbers, no space between `-s` and the following number, extra arguments, or no arguments at all)
- It should in principle be able to handle any number of digits and any positive size for the scale parameter `-s`. So only external factors like the maximum command line length of the shell should limit these parameters.
- Non-printable characters are allowed, but your program must consist of the 128 characters of the ASCII set.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I can't see a ruby solution under <200 bytes there, so my question is still open. And doing the parameter parsing is an important aspect of the problem.

Comment: This should have tag [tag:Ruby].

Comment: I thought about that but thought it might discourage other language submissions. But I added it now anyway, because of my ruby specific question. But I still hope people don't think answers should be limited to ruby.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think the input parsing is not a sufficiently substantial difference to not make this a duplicate. The core challenge is encoding the digits in a scalable way, and that is the same in both challenges. Since you're specifically looking for a short Ruby answer, I'd say the way to go is to offer a bounty on the old question instead of asking it again. And lastly, I think you had it right, the Ruby tag is misplaced here, as it suggests that you're looking for Ruby answers only.

Comment: @MartinBüttner the biggest difference isn't the input parsing, it's that the other one is a popularity contest whereas this is codegolf. However, bounty awarders get to decide their own criteria, distinct from the OP's, so I guess your suggestion is right.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: The output suggested in the other problem is different from my specification. Also it doesn't even seem to be enforced, since the answers use quite different styles. I'm sorry but I can not possible see how giving a bounty to the other question can answer my question. And as steveverrill mentions it's not even a codegolf contest.

Comment: @steveverrill You've got reopen-vote privileges. David, true, the format is slightly different, but I don't think adapting the format will make a big difference in terms of code size. And I agree that our duplicate policies are a bit harsh sometimes (and I'd personally prefer them to be relaxed a bit). Feel free to join us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) if you want to discuss this. In the meantime I don't think the other being a popcon should stop you from putting up a bounty for short code. It's just one way to gather popularity.

Comment: David, there's nothing in the other question that says you must follow the OP's spec, and a PopCon encourages people to deviate. That type of question is often closed as an art contest (and so off topic) these days. Your question is a proper rigidly specified code golf, so I've decided to cast a reopen vote. One comment: I hate that you want input accepted in any order, it has nothing to do with meat of the challenge. @MartinBüttner I have the privilege but I must decide how to use it. David's "not enforced" comment convinced me to check: The answers to the previous question dont work here.

Comment: @steveverill: Ok, I removed the "any order" requirement. I like answers to be valid solutions for the original ruby quiz, but it doesn't specifcy this requirement explicitely, even though the sample answers in the book fulfill it.